# Module not found when moving file outside directory. Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a project and I'm doing unit testing for it. I want to have my testing be in it's own folder and the main file be outside that folder in the main folder. For some reason even with the correct import names it gives me a module main not found error

```
[test.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/021rN.png)
[main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQZPt.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Nx7.png)
```

I've tried different variations of imports and deleting my cache so far, but I'm not really sure what else to do. This feels like some misunderstanding I have about how imports work but I'm not really sure.

Comment: It gives me an "invalid syntax" error for `[test.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/021rN.png)`.

Comment: Please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors